# display list item Property

Tags: html, css

Can you help me understand better the `display:list-item` property? Does it behave like "inline" element? Does it behave like "block" element or maybe "inline-block"?
Thanks in advance to all the helpers

Comment: Maybe you could try to explain us your goal. Because, list-item behave like a list of item... now what? What do you need exactly ?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-display

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-value-summary

Answer (score 1):

```
display : block
```

A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

```
display:list-item
```

An element rendered as a list-item element will have the same behaviour than a block element.It lets the element behave as a list-item.

Refer this link to understand it using an example.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=list-item